# How to use Github API v3 to create Pull Request reviews?

Tags: python, curl, post, github-api

On the Github API v3 docs, there is an article on [how to create a pull request review using the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#create-a-review-request).

There is this line :

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/requested_reviewers
```

Can someone explain me with an example as what to do with this? A curl command would have been more preferrable. What I can guess is that its some format for the POST message, but how to fire the POST call?

Any help with any example will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Figured out a way myself, but would love to see some Pythonic way as well, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

So after a bit of trying on my own, I figured out what this actually means and how to use these calls. Sharing this for future visitors.

The terms starting with `:` are actually variables and need to be replaced with values. So, taking the example of creating pull request reviews , the curl command would look like this :

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner-username>/<project-name>/pulls/<pull-number>/requested_reviewers?access_token=<personal-access-token-for-github>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"reviewers\":[\"reviewer1\"]}"
```

Similarly, you can follow the format specified in Github API docs for other cases, and generate curl calls.

Answer (score 1):

For the pythonic way, you can use a subclass of `string.Template`.

Taking your example:

```
from string import Template

class URLTemplate(Template):
    delimiter = ':'

post_url = URLTemplate('/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/requested_reviewers')
post_param = {
    'owner': 'myself',
    'repo': 'secret_one'
}

print(post_url.substitute(number=42, **post_param))
```

Will produce:

```
/repos/myself/secret_one/pulls/42/requested_reviewers
```